Jenkins working as unstable, each jobs is failing very frequently, using Jenkins version 2.375.1
Very frequently Jenkins jobs are failing. behavior of hits issue is very frequent.
How to troubleshoot this? When we are running few jobs that was working fine. when some jobs are failed, after multiple retry of 5-6 execution it gets successful.

Have you checked the logs?

yes, but there are lots of warning over there in logs and few exceptions trace but on log level of warning.

I am not sure Jenkins has any magic way of troubleshooting. Look at the errors you get, think about them, find solutions or workarounds. Not sure what you are expecting to hear...

Thanks for your time, I understood your comments, I will provide the logs here to find the solution
